# How to make an "X" through circle in jython?

Tags: image, line, jython, geometry, jes

I have no idea how to do this. I need to draw two lines that make an X through a circle, where the starting and end points would be on the circumference of the circle. If anybody could even give me a direction to go in to do this, it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Get the maths right first.

The most general case of circle-line intersection is described here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html

But if the center of the circle is the origin, its radius is 1, and the lines are forming an x, so a 45 degree angle with the horizontal and vertical axes, it is quite a bit more simple:

The circle is defined by

> x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = 1

The line with 45 degree slope is defined by

> y = x

Their intersections are the points (x,y) where both statements are true so

> x<sup>2</sup> + x<sup>2</sup> = 1
>
> 2 x<sup>2</sup> = 1
>
> x<sup>2</sup> = 1/2
>
> x = sqrt(1/2) or x = -sqrt(1/2) and y = x
>
> so points (sqrt(1/2), sqrt(1/2)) and (-sqrt(1/2), -sqrt(1/2))

Same for the other line.

One line goes from `(-sqrt(0.5), -sqrt(0.5))` (bottom left) to `(sqrt(0.5), sqrt(0.5))` (top right) and the other from `(-sqrt(0.5), sqrt(0.5))` (top left) to `(sqrt(0.5), -sqrt(0.5))` (bottom right).

[image: Wolfram Alpha generated picture]

[On Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=circle+with+radius+1+and+line+segment+from+%28-+sqrt%28.5%29%2C+-+sqrt%28.5%29%29+to+%28sqrt%28.5%29%2C+sqrt%28.5%29%29++and+line+segment+from+%28-+sqrt%28.5%29%2C+sqrt%28.5%29%29+to+%28+sqrt%28.5%29%2C+-sqrt%28.5%29%29)